# Spring integration poller XML configuration with spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, xml-configuration, poller

I am working on a project in spring boot and I need to add Spring integration poller for polling files from a location and run spring batch on that file to process it.

I have used spring batch integration for this(Document Reference below.)

http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/springBatchIntegration.html

In spring boot, I have succesfully configured my poller in @Configuration file as below

```
@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(value = "fileInputChannel", poller = @Poller(
  fixedRate = "1000"), autoStartup = "true")
public MessageSource<File> filesScanner() {
  CompositeFileListFilter<File> filters = new   CompositeFileListFilter<File>();
  filters.addFilter(new   SimplePatternFileListFilter("*.xml"));
  filters.addFilter(new AcceptOnceFileListFilter<File>());
  filters.addFilter(getLastModifiedFileFilter());
  FileReadingMessageSource source = new FileReadingMessageSource();
  source.setDirectory(new File("F:/DataInput/"));
  source.setFilter(filters);
  return source;
}
```

This poller is defined in java configuration whereas the channels are defined in xml as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
  xmlns:int-file="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file/spring-integration-file.xsd">
    <int:channel id="ticketingResponse" />
    <int:channel id="mailFailureTicketData" />
    <int:channel id="moveSuccessTicketingFile" />
    <int:channel id="moveFailureTicketingFile" />
    <int:channel id="ticketingFileInput" />
    <int:channel id="ticketingJobParameters" />
    <!-- <int-file:inbound-channel-adapter id="filePoller"
    channel="inboundFileChannel"
    directory="file:/tmp/myfiles/"
    filename-pattern="*.csv">
  <int:poller fixed-rate="1000"/>
</int-file:inbound-channel-adapter> -->
    <bean id="earliestTicketingFileSelecter" class="com.avios.integration.iqcx.FilesSortingComparator" />
    <bean id="compositeFilesFilter"
        class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.CompositeFileListFilter">
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.RegexPatternFileListFilter">
                    <constructor-arg name="pattern" value="${ticketing.input.file.pattern}" />
                </bean>
                <bean class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters." />
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.LastModifiedFileListFilter">
                    <property name="age" value="${ticketing.input.file.age}" />
                </bean>
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
    <bean id="ticketingFilesScanner"
    class="org.springframework.integration.file.FileReadingMessageSource">
    <property name="filter" value="compositeFilesFilter" />
    <property name="directory" value="/tmp/myfiles/" />
</bean>
<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter id="filePoller"
    channel="inboundFileChannel"
    directory="file:/tmp/myfiles/"
    filename-pattern="*.csv">
  <int:poller fixed-rate="1000"/>
</int-file:inbound-channel-adapter><!-- <int-file:inbound-channel-adapter
        directory="${ticketing.input.file.path}" channel="ticketingFileInput"
        comparator="earliestTicketingFileSelecter" auto-startup="true" filter="compositeFilesFilter" >
        <int:poller ></int:poller>
        </int-file:inbound-channel-adapter> -->
    <int:transformer id="iqcxFilesToJobParameters" ref="jobParameterTransformer"
        input-channel="ticketingFileInput" method="addTicketingFileToJobParameter"
        output-channel="ticketingJobParameters"  />
    <int:outbound-channel-adapter channel="ticketingJobParameters"
        ref="iqcxJobLaunchingGateway" method="handleMessage" />

</beans>
```

I am getting the below error in my XML configuration file.

**cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'fixed-rate' is not allowed to appear in element 'int:poller'.**

I checked this on google and found only the below link which wasn't much of use as i am getting exact same error.

[Using Spring Boot & Spring Integration with database backed Configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33403056/using-spring-boot-spring-integration-with-database-backed-configuration)

[Attribute 'fixed-rate' is not allowed to appear in element 'int:poller'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28625635/attribute-fixed-rate-is-not-allowed-to-appear-in-element-intpoller)

Spring boot version i am using is as below.

```
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.6.RELEASE</version>
```

Spring integration jar in library - **Spring-integration-core-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar**

I also tried excluding integration jar from batch-integration dependency and adding it separately as below but that didn't work either.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-batch-integration</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.integration/spring-integration-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Also checked the XSD http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd and it has the attribute fixed-delay in poller. Any suggestions for resolving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the important note in the online schema:

> +++++ IMPORTANT +++++
>
> ```
> This schema is for the 1.0 version of Spring Integration Core. We cannot update it to the current schema
>  because that will break any applications using 1.0.3 or lower. For subsequent versions, the unversioned
>  schema is resolved from the classpath and obtained from the jar.
>  Please refer to github:
> ```
>
> https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/tree/master/spring-integration-core/src/main/resources/org/springframework/integration/config/xml
>
> ```
> for the latest schema.
> ```

In the old schema, fixed-rate was part of a periodic trigger child element on the poller.

The 4.2 schema is [here](http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration-4.2.xsd).

If this is just an IDE error, you can ignore it, or configure your IDE to be "spring aware".

Spring finds the actual schema on the classpath.

With STS, enable "spring nature" on the project.

Comment: The IDE was the issue. I ran my application with the error still there in XML and it ran successfully with the XML configuration as well. Didn't try that earlier. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Try to enable the Spring nature in STS4: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49201689/enable-spring-project-nature-in-sts-4/49201841#49201841 with no luck.  Any suggestions? TIA

Answer (score 0):

sometimes it could be due to missing  spring-boot-starter-integration & spring-integration-file dependency in pom.xml. So check if actually spring-integration-file dependency is available in your project when you are using spring integration.

Comment: If it was a dependency issue my annotation based confiuration would have also failed. But that is working without nay errors. The issue is only with the XML configuration. Also as per Gary's suggestion, i ran my application with the error still there in XML and application ran successfully.

Comment: oh ok, i was not sure if you are getting this during run time. I had a similar  issue over the weekend where i was trying to migrate an existing project to spring boot. glad that you got around it.